# In laravel,why get data from collection was wrong?

Tags: laravel, collections, model

I use `model::where()->get()`get a collection . dd($collection),the data was right ,but if I dd($collection->value) was wrong .But weird,just only one value was wrong ,other was right。

I use $collection->value many times ,never happen mistake.In picture,order_id was wrong when get it alone.
[image]

use dd($item->order_id) ,I can get a variable

```
9223372036854775807
```

use dd($item) , I can get

```
"order_id" => "2017071413381900000000111048"

"fee" => 1

"user_id" => "11"

"device_id" => 865209038904828

"operater_id" => 15757831834

"state" => 0

"payway" => 2

"created_at" => "2017-07-14 13:38:19"

"updated_at" => "2017-07-14 13:38:19"
```

the order_id was different.

UPDATE :Model

`class WeixinPayRecord extends Model`

`{   protected $table = 'weixin_pay_record';`

`protected $primaryKey = 'order_id';`

`}`

Comment: Show us the results of the dumps.  Best to use text and proper formatting rather than images.

Comment: What do you mean with "it was wrong"? Did you get an error or do you get a wrong value? If so, what is the error or the wrong value?

Comment: I show the output ,i get a wrong value ,see the output.

Comment: @Devon  I show the output ，use var_dump($item->order_id).the variable type was Integer.but actually it was a string

Comment: Do you have some sort of casting or a mutator in your model?  Seems like you're hitting the upper limit for a 64-bit integer.

Comment: @Devon  In this Controller ,I never sort ,maybe in other Controller sort model.But why I get $item->order_id was a Integer ?

Comment: Post your model code.

Comment: @Devon see UPDATE

Comment: That is strange that it is converting that value to an integer if you don't have any mutation in your model.  I'd have to dig into Laravel's code to see why that would happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be trying to convert order_id to an integer, however, the upper limit for an signed integer in 64-bit is 2^63-1 (your wrong value).

As of Laravel 5.4 (only code I researched), Eloquent shouldn't be changing the type of your value unless you have something defined in the `$casts` property of the model.

If you can't find the reason for the casting, a workaround I'd recommend is using a mutator to force it to a string.  A mutator will take precedence over a cast. In your model add the following method:

```
public function getOrderIdAttribute()
{
    return (string) $this->attributes['order_id'];
}
```

Comment: Actually, I use  `dd( (string)$item->order_id)`.I only get a string type "9223372036854775807".

Comment: OMG,I use your function ,and `foreach($collection as $item){ $item->getOrderIdAttribute();}`.It can get a right value.But Why $item->order_id was get a wrong value?

Comment: Like I tried to explain, something is casting your string to an integer.  Can't really tell you more without digging through your code base.  You don't need to call getOrderIdAttribute(), it is a mutator, it will be called when you access order_id

Comment: Sorry ,I don't understand.Now,I use `$item->order_id;`,it can get right value.You said getOrderIdAttribute() is a mutator, I have no concept  about matator, this function when is called ?

Comment: Thanks for your help,I will search some data about matator.